# How to display wishlist item details in admin panel of magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, wishlist, items

I wants to display 'wishlist_item' and 'wishlist' table details on admin panel of magento.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :

```
$wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist');     
$wishlistCollection = $wishlist->getCollection();
$select =  $wishlistCollection->getSelect();
$select->join(array("t1" => 'wishlist_item'),
"main_table.wishlist_id = t1.wishlist_id",array('wishlist_id' => 
'main_table.wishlist_id','t1.*'));
  // $select->group('main_table.wishlist_id');
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($wishlistCollection->getData());
```

Comment: where to add this code?

Comment: please specify file path to add this code

Comment: You need create a module. I create one module and they print the wishlist using the code of this reply.


Module: https://github.com/reynaldots/magento_ShowWishlist/